# g++ - Finding appopriate Windows libraries to link so as to compile FANN library

Tags: c++, compilation, fann

For various reasons I have been trying to compile the [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/) library myself. I'm on Windows 10 with MinGW. To keep things simple I was going for something like this to start with:

```
g++ mushroom.c -o shroom.exe -lm -I src\ -I src\include\ src\doublefann.c
```

(`mushroom.c` includes `<stdio.h>` and `"fann.h"`.)

Using the `-I src\ -I src\include\ src\doublefann.c` allowed me to get rid of various undefined reference errors resulting from header files not being found, but it now keeps throwing the following undefined reference:

```
doublefann.c:(.text+0x4ee9): undefined reference to GetTickCount()
```

FYI, this appears in fann.h (line 54):

```
/* COMPAT_TIME REPLACEMENT */ 
#ifndef _WIN32
#include <sys/time.h>
#else   /* _WIN32 */
#if !defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS) && !defined(_INC_WINDOWS)  
extern unsigned long __stdcall GetTickCount(void);
```

In short, this seems to be an error with linking windows libraries, and I don't really know how to proceed so as to find the relevant ones to link.

Here is the full [fann.h](http://pastebin.com/gTrHCYAg) and the full [doublefann.c](http://pastebin.com/mrHKJi8C)

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a **linker** error, not a **compiler** error, i.e. any include directories added via `-I ...` don't matter. Those are only important if the compiler cannot find header files. You need to add the appropriate library with `-l...`. (Which one that would be... sorry, Windows / MinGW is not my forte.)

Comment: Well that was one issue, so adding those directories I mentioned above let it find the relevant header files. This seems to be a pure linker error, and I'm just looking for what the relevant libraries to include with -l might be. Anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## DISCLAIMERS AND NOTES

EDIT: Since going to bed last night, I refined my approach so you don't have to edit the actual FANN source files. (For the record, my original approach worked and you can look at the edit history to see what that was if you really care).

Firstly, for anyone else stumbling across this question, I should note that it's not really necessary to use FANN this way. The website provides cmake files as well as Visual Studio Solutions that both work fine.

## WHATS WRONG

Looking back at the question, the problem is obvious and I hate myself for not seeing it before the first of way too many hours. You'll notice that all of the files in that command have the `*.c` extension. Forgive me for treating you like a novice, but I can't assume you know anything or I risk giving a bad answer. `*.c` is the canonical file extension for *C* source files. The gnu toolchain is a fairly flexible piece of software, and you **can** compile *C* code with `g++` without errors most of the time. But you shouldn't, because you'll get this error. Since your source file, `mushroom.c`, is a *C* source file, it'll work for you to just compile the code as *C* (in this case with `gcc`, not `g++`). If, however, you're using things in your program like `iostream` or `string` or classes or any other *C++* code, you're right to compile it as *C++* (by convention you would change the extension then to `*.cpp` for clarification, but I'm not sure the GNU toolchain cares). In that case, whenever you want to include *C* code in your *C++* program, be sure to wrap it in an `extern "C"{}`, so that the compiler knows the calling conventions and labels are *C* standard, which isn't always the same as *C++* standard. This means that not only does calling *C* code from *C++* without `extern "C"` risk passing arguments to functions in the wrong way (good way to cause a segfault), but the way variables and functions are renamed when compiled to assembly is different between the two languages, which is why you get `Undefined Reference` in the linking stage, but not the compiling stage. In this case, not only is `doublefann.c` a *C* source file (which by itself links fine), but so is the library that contains the function declaration of `GetTickCount()`. Specifically, you're linking to `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\kernel32.dll` (normally, but I believe MinGW uses `PATH_TO_MinGW\lib\lib32k.a`), which defines how programs can interact with the Windows Operating System at the machine-code level. The `__stdcall` utility is defined here to call things like `GetTickCount()` from the OS, which are assembly functions, within *C* code. Because this is in a `*.dll`, the compiler cannot change `__stdcall` to suit *C++* coventions. This is due to the fact that "`dll`" stands for "**Dynamically Linked Library**". Essentially this means that these files were already compiled into machine code when Windows (or MinGW) was installed. So editing it is nonsensical, because you'd need to have intimate working knowledge of the opcodes for every x86_64 processor ever made. Thus, calling in *C* will do everything in a way that `__stdcall` expects, but calling in *C++* requires the `extern "C"`, or it'll mangle the names of your function declaration and possibly cause runtime errors.

#### tl;dr

FANN is written in *C*, *C*=/=*C++*, so don't expect a *C++* compiler to always compile *C* code perfectly.

## Solution

There are two ways to go about solving this problem.

### 1

If you're using *C++* features/libraries, change the name of your source code to `mushroom.cpp` (if you want) and change the line (wherever it occurs in your program)

```
#include "doublefann.c"
```

to be wrapped like so:

```
extern "C"{
    #include "doublefann.c"
}
```

If you read through fann.h, you might have noticed the lines:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus //line 65
extern "C"
{

#ifndef __cplusplus
} /* to fool automatic indention engines */ 
#endif
#endif  /* __cplusplus */
```

Don't worry, these don't appear to conflict. Frankly, I'm not sure what these lines are meant to accomplish, but I'm sure they know what they're doing.

### 2

If `mushroom.c` really is just pure *C*, just compile using:

```
gcc -o shroom.exe mushroom.c -lm -I src\ -I src\ -I src\include\ src\doublefann.c -Wall
```

and that should work. I added `-Wall` because I love being able to make my code absolutely perfect, feel free to leave that out it just prints every warning you could have.

Comment: Very elaborate, and mostly wrong. @Shakespeare: The solution is really a lot simpler: `1` Compile the library as C code (using gcc or the -x <language> compiler option). `2` `#include <windows.h>` before `#include fann.h` in your code. `3` Link against the required system libraries. For [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408.aspx) that would be *kernel32.lib*. Unlike written in this answer, `extern "C"` does **not** specify a calling convention. It controls how symbols are decorated. `__stdcall`, on the other hand, specifies the calling convention.

Comment: @IInspectable I have tried it and it worked, but the magic sauce (as we now expected) was only to compile with gcc as opposed to g++, the other things you mentioned were (at least at this stage) unnecessary; Which makes me like ocket's answer which elegantly seems to make that code be treated as the c code it should be interpreted as